# Randomly chose between 0 and 1

Tags: c++, random

Here is the function that I created:

```
tJugador quienEmpieza(){
    rand()
    tJugador whoStarts = tJugador(rand() % 2); // randomly assigns player
    return whoStarts;
```

I want it select either 0 or 1 randomly. It selects 0 every time. A caculator game that is supposed to randomnly select player Persona or player Automata. I just need help in figuring out how to make the function select either 0 or 1.

Here is the whole program with the suggested changes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int Meta = 31;
enum tJugador { Automata, Persona };


tJugador quienEmpieza();
tJugador pasalacalculador();

int digitoAleatorio();
int digitoAutomata(int ultimo);

int digitoPersona();
int digitoPersona(int ultimo);

bool mismaFila(int ultimo, int nuevo);
bool mismaColumna(int ultimo, int nuevo);
bool digitoValido(int ultimo, int nuevo);



int main()

{
    std::srand(time(NULL));

    int pasalacalculadora();
    int whoStarts = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int suma;
    suma = 0;
    string nom;
    int ultimo;
    ultimo = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int next = 0;

    cout << "Bienvenido a Pasa La Calculadora!" << endl;
    cout << "Como Te llamas?";
    cin >> nom;
    cout << "Hola:" << nom << endl;
    cout << "Empiezas:";

    if (whoStarts == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Automata" << endl;


    }
    else if (whoStarts == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Persona" << endl;

    }


    while ((x != 0) && (suma < Meta)) {

        cout << "Introduce un numero (0 para abandonar): ";
        cin >> d;

        cout << "Suma =" << suma << endl;

        if (whoStarts == Automata){

            d = digitoAutomata(ultimo);
            suma = suma + d;
            ultimo = d;
            next = Persona;
        }

        if (whoStarts == Persona){

            x = digitoPersona();
            suma = suma + x;
            ultimo = x;
            next = Automata;
        }


    }
    cin.sync();
        cin.get();
        system("pause");
        return next;

}



tJugador quienEmpieza(){
    rand();
    tJugador whoStarts = tJugador(rand() % 2); // randomly assigns player
    return whoStarts;
}




int digitoAleatorio(){
    return (rand() % 9) + 1;                                 // randomly assigns a number


    if (quienEmpieza == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Introduce un digito:" << digitoAleatorio << endl;
        std::cout << ("Suma:") << digitoAleatorio << endl;

    }


}

int digitoAutomata(int ultimo){
    bool validDigit = false;
    int digitoAleatorio = 0;
    int d = 0;

    if (digitoAleatorio == validDigit) {

        (d = true);



        return d;
    }
}


int digitoPersona(){
    int x;
    int whoStarts = 0;

    if (whoStarts == 1)
    {
        cout << "Introduce un numero entre 0 y 9(0 para abandonar): ";
        cin >> x;
    }

    if ((x >= 1) && (x <= 9))

    {
        cout << ("Suma:") << x << endl;
    }
    return x;
}    
}
```

Comment: What exactly tJugador does? Post the code. By the way, whoStarts is of type 'tJugador' not 'int'

Comment: it chooses either persona or automata

Comment: I don't see where you are calling the function `quienEmpienza`. In your function, `digitoAleatorio` you have an if statement checking `quienEmpieza == 0`
, but where is this global variable? Maybe you wanted to call the function? So it would be `quienEmpieza() == 0` ?

Answer (score 2):

I see a few problems with your approach:

- you're using `%3` which should select a random number from `{0,1,2}`
- you're initializing the seed each time you call random

Generally, you should initialize your random number generator only once, and then make multiple calls to `rand()`. So my question is: how many times did you call `rand()` to evaluate the distribution of the values generated?

The thing with random numbers is that they are random so it's entriely possible that calling `rand()` two or three times will generate three consecutive `0` values. On top of that `rand()` is a pseudo-random number generator which means it's not quite random, it's only *designed* to look random.

To evaluate the distribution of results you should generate a few thousand numbers (or even tens, or hundreds of thousands) and then see if the number of `0`s is approximately equal to the number of `1`s you get.

Answer (score -3):

use srand **once** at the beginning of your program, e.g.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(nullptr));
    // do work
}
```

I would generate numbers from a larger spectrum, eg. 1000 and check if the number is odd or even and thus determine 0 or 1
e.g.

```
num = rand() % 1000;
if (num % 2 == 0)
    // 0
else
    // 1
// or the other way around
//or simply go
rand() % 2;  // was % 1
```

Comment: `rand() % 1` will always be zero.

Comment: Oh big deal, with all the languages and non-standards I mixed up that it is an open Intervall, so sorry... will correct